# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#

когда вызываю функцию происходит ошибка => Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
можете помочь решить эту проблему

```
public static Resp<List<Pers>> Getc()
    {
     var resp = new Resp<List<Pers>>(){Value = new List<Pers>}
     using (var c = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.MyConnection))
     using(var cm = new OracleCommana("procedureName, c"))
     {
       var cur = new OracleParameter("R", Oracle.Cursor);
    
       racleDataReader read;
       cmd.CommandType = commandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Clear();
       cmd.Parameters.Add(cur);
       cmd.Connection.Open();
    
      while(reader.Read())
      {
        var rec = new Pers();
        record.Acct = Convert.ToInt32(reader["T"]);
        record.Ac = reader["acco"].Tostring();
        record.Date = Convert.ToDatetime(reader[date]);
        resp.VAlue.Add(rec);
      }
     }
       return resp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если где-то у вас может прийти `null` из БД, то нужно это явно проверять:

```
record.Acct = reader["T"] == DBNull.Value ? (Int32?) null : Convert.ToInt32(reader["T"]);
```

Ну или если использовать как специальное значение `0` или там `-1`, а не `null`, то можно использовать обычный `int`, а не `nullable`:

```
record.Acct = reader["T"] == DBNull.Value ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["T"]);
```